# How to implement fetching an event time for a requested day/date in Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am beginner developing Alexa skills, I have a set of event time's (ex 7:00 AM - 3:30PM) predefined for a calendar month.
How to develop a skill, where user asks for the event time for a given date?

Here is the scenario.. User:- Alexa get me event time on <31 dec/today/tomarrow>..  Alexa:- it starts from 7:00AM to 3:30 PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the solutions I think might work is, At launch ask the user whether he wants to know the events for today, tomorrow, next week or any day and when the user responds grab the date using the `AMAZON.DATE` slot and ask for the time he wants to fetch the events from using `AMAZON.TIME` then use that date and time to get the events.

Comment: Thanks Sharan, Actully user request for a the time, the output from alexa should be time. Here is the scenario.. User:- Alexa get me event time on <31 dec/today/tomarrow>..  Alexa:- it starts from 7:00AM to 3:30 PM

Comment: Can you give me the flow of the conversation of the Alexa and user in a neat way so that I can understand your problem clearly?

Comment: user: Alexa Open Event Manger ..  Alexa: Hello, Welcome..  User:- what time does party starts on 31 Dec.. Alexa:- It starts from 7:00PM -11:00 PM ..  User:- what time does party starts 12 Jan 2020 .. Alexa:- It starts from 2:00 PM - 4:00 PM

Comment: I got your question, First, if you have the start time and end time of the event then when the user asks for the particular event or as you said just date then fetch the start and end time of the event and then concatenate with your response like  `It starts from starttime to endtime`.